# nginx virtual host: php5-fpm-sock error

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, php

I am trying to set a virtual host for a fresh ubuntu/php5.5/nginx installation as such

etc/nginx/sites_available/mydomain.com :

```
 server {
listen  80 default_server;
root    /home/www/mydomain.com/public/;
index index.php index.html
access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;
server_name mydomain.com;

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri =404;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    fastcgi_read_timeout 240;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}
 }
```

etc/hosts :

```
 127.0.0.1 mydomain.com
```

symlink in the symlink in the 'sites-enabled' folder :

```
 sudo ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/mydomain.com /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com
```

the

```
 service nginx restart
```

fail and the var/log/nginx/error.log gives

```
 no port in upstream "php5-fpm-sock" in /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/mydomain.com:12
```

what can be wrong?

Comment: http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_fastcgi_module.html#fastcgi_pass

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fpm adress path was missing:

```
 nano /etc/nginx/conf.d/php5-fpm.conf
```

edit :

```
upstream php5-fpm-sock {
    server unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
}
```

Comment: It is unfortunate how bad the documentation is around this. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing php-fpm path setting.

```
fastcgi_pass php5-fpm-sock;
```

You have not point php-fpm to listen. change it to.

```
fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
```

or

```
fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
```